# Anonymous function type signature

Tags: haskell

I was learning anonymous functions in haskell.

```
mTH3 x = (\y -> \z -> x*y*z)
```

The type signature for this comes out to be

```
*Main> :t mTH3
mTH3 :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

Whereas for this function

```
mTH4 = (\x -> \y -> \z -> x*y*z)
```

It comes out to be

```
*Main> :t mTH4
mTH4 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

What is the reason of difference between them. Why isn't the type signature for second function same as first. If I try to define type signature of the second function like this :

```
mTH4 :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
mTH4 = (\x -> \y -> \z -> x*y*z)
```

Then the output is same as the `mTH3` function.

Comment: I just tried it in `ghci` and they have the same signature `Num a => a -> a -> a -> a`.

Comment: @zoran119 GHCi behaves differently from compiling with ghc, by default. See the question linked above by chepner.